# How to compatible for Retina 3.5 and 4 in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have an app perfectly designed for iPhone 4s and 5s. But I am worrying about Retina 3.5 and 4 displays.

I am using xib ie; Retina 4 in iPhone, I am running in simulator or iphone 5s with retina 4 .

But UIElements are missing while running the program in Retina 3.5.

How to make the app compatible for Retina 3.5 and 4

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look the auto layout.

Comment: Without autolayouts can we??

Comment: Yes, but very difficult, you should caculate the UIElements frame in the code.